# Cant make an SSL request with perl

Tags: perl, ssl

Here is my code

```
use LWP::UserAgent;
use HTTP::Request::Common qw(POST);
use HTTP::Cookies;
use LWP::Protocol::https;
use strict;
use warnings;
use CACertOrg::CA;


my $URL="https://ta.example.co.il/f5-w-687474703a2f2f746573742e636c616c6e65742e636f2e696c$$/toolsandforms/specialissearch/policysearch/Pages/default.aspx";
my $UA = LWP::UserAgent->new();

my $xml = <<XMLREQUEST;

__SPSCEditMenu=true
XMLREQUEST

$UA->ssl_opts(
     SSL_verify_mode   => 'SSL_VERIFY_NONE',
);

my $req =HTTP::Request::Common::POST("$URL",
   Content_type=>'form-data',
   Content =>$xml
);

$req->header('Cookie' =>q( Cookie: TIN=294000; LastMRH_Session=ca480946; MRHSession=7e53c7507df395d38a2eb230ca480946; F5_ST=1382338632c900c100c1382338632c604800c600c; MRHSequence=1382338609),
             'DNT'=>'1',
             'Referer'=> 'https://ta.example.co.il/f5-w-687474703a2f2f746573742e636c616c6e65742e636f2e696c$$/testing/notificationsandalerts/Pages/Default.aspx?txtTabID=0&txtType=1',
             'User-Agent'=>'Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/6.0; EIE10;HEILMSN',
             'Content-Type'=>'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');


my $response=$UA->request($req);

if ($response->is_success) {
  print $response->decoded_content;  
}
else {
  die $response->status_line;  
}
```

I get this error in eclipse.

> write failed:  at C:/Perl/lib/LWP/Protocol/http.pm line 356.
>   500 write failed:  at C:/Perl/Workplace/P1/SimpleCSRF.pl line 41.

Why is it failed to write? It is a simple request to an ssl page?
How can I enable more verbose debugging to see what is being returned?

I also tried with SSL easy and I get 302 response each time.

```
use strict;
```

use warnings;
use Net::SSLeay qw(get_https post_https sslcat make_headers make_form);

```
my $head=<<HEADREQUEST;
           Host: ta.example.co.il
            Connection: keep-alive
            Content-Length: 154768
            Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
            Origin: https://ta.example.co.il
            User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/30.0.1599.101 Safari/537.36
            Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
            Referer: https://ta.example.co.il/f5-w-687474703a2f2f746573742e636c616c6e65742e636f2e696c$$/testing/notificationsandalerts/Pages/Default.aspx?txtTabID=0&txtType=1
            Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
            Accept-Language: en,en-US;q=0.8
            Cookie: TIN=15000; LastMRH_Session=8acc0244; MRHSession=f5d160f7be2a40e290cd37f38acc0244; MRHSequence=1382340967; F5_ST=1382340968c900c100c1382340968c604800c600c
HEADREQUEST

my $body=<<BODY;
AGRkZAIDDc_46c9_9a5a_167e29fefb40%24txtCSRFValidation=&ctl00%24SPWebPartManager1%24g_137a0e02_1a49_45df_a17f_45dd7b48cbca%24txtCSRFValidation=
BODY
my $url='/f5-w-687474703a2f2f746573742e636c616c6e65742e636f2e696c$$/testing/notificationsandalerts/Pages/Default.aspx?txtTabID=0&txtType=1 ';
my ($page, $response, %reply_headers)= post_https('ta.example.co.il', 443, $url, $head,$body );


     print $response;
```

Comment: Isn't this the same question as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19479615/failed-to-write-ssl-request-with-perl ?

Comment: It's the same problem, but slightly simplified (no date handling, no threads). Still, this is far from a minimal test case to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: See update! It doesnt even work with SSLeasy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What versions are you using from each of the modules? Which perl version are you using?

Did they installed well?

If it helps, there are ppm packages for both Net::SSLeay at the sisyphusion repo (and probably elsewhere, too):

```
ppm install http://www.sisyphusion.tk/ppm/Net-SSLeay.ppd
```

I used this code, and it was worked.

```
use LWP::UserAgent;
use HTTP::Request::Common;

use Data::Dumper;


local $ENV{'HTTPS_DEBUG'} = 1; # Will show SSL assertions

my $URL="https://www.google.com/";
my $UA = LWP::UserAgent->new();

my $xml = <<XMLREQUEST;

__SPSCEditMenu=true
XMLREQUEST

$UA->ssl_opts(
     SSL_verify_mode   => 'SSL_VERIFY_NONE',
);

my $req =HTTP::Request::Common::POST("$URL",
   Content_type=>'form-data',
   Content =>$xml
);

$req->header('Cookie' =>q( Cookie: TIN=294000; LastMRH_Session=ca480946; MRHSession=7e53c7507df395d38a2eb230ca480946; F5_ST=1382338632c900c100c1382338632c604800c600c; MRHSequence=1382338609),
             'DNT'=>'1',
             'Referer'=> 'https://google.co.uk',
             'User-Agent'=>'Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/6.0; EIE10;HEILMSN',
             'Content-Type'=>'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');

print Dumper($req);
```

Comment: Thanks for the tips. I will explore with it a bit. I get a different error code

Comment: verify_hostname  needs to be set to 1.  Otherwise you have a security hole.  ssl_opts => { verify_hostname => 1 };